# Redirect if a URL contains this string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I don't know much about .htaccess, but I'm trying to help a friend who recently moved his blog to Wordpress.

We need to redirect the OLD archive pages like this:

- www.domain.com/2010_04_01_archive.html
- www.domain.com/2010_04_02_archive.html
- www.domain.com/2010_04_03_archive.html

to NEW archive pages like this:

- www.domain.com/2010/04/01
- www.domain.com/2010/04/02
- www.domain.com/2010/04/03

I've tried everything I can find using htaccess redirect and rewrite, but again, I don't really know what I'm doing with htaccess!

Thanks so much for your help, 
Amanda

OK tried this:

## Turn mod_rewrite on

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})*([0-9]{2})*([0-9]{2})_archive.html$ /$1/$2/$3 [L,R=301]

in .htaccess in the very top level folder of my site. Still, when I go to http://www.bikermetric.com/2010_04_01_archive.html, it doesn't redirect.

Just tried this too: 
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})*([0-9]{2})*([0-9]{2})_archive.html$ /$1/$2/$3

Still nothing.

Comment: Try this http://www.htaccessredirect.net/. It might help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll generally get better responses if you include the code you've already tried in your question. What have you already tried that didn't work?

Comment: Thanks spaceman, but that only only allows my to do 1 to 1 redirects... Ok, thanks CoderDennis! Will do from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mod_alias or mod_rewrite here. You'll want to stick with using mod_rewrite if you already have rewrite rules (stuff that look like `RewriteEngine` or `RewriteRule`):

mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_archive.html$ /$1/$2/$3
```

mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_archive.html$ /$1/$2/$3 [L,R=301]
```

You'd want to add it to the htaccess file *in your document root*.

Comment: Ok got it!

Jon Lin, your

RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})_([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{2})_archive.html$ /$1/$2/$3 

did work.

I deleted another .htaccess file in the next level up folder, and cleared my browser cache. After that, it worked.

Thanks for your help!